# Ember component this.set() dosen't rerender

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I find it strange that `this.set` doesn't update the component.
The template code is like that:

```
{{#each data as |d|}}
    <span value={{d.key}} class="checked-normal" onclick={{action 'chooseBp' d.key}}>
        {{d.value}}
    <i class="fa checked-i"></i>
    </span>
{{/each}}
```

The js is like:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
didReceiveAttrs(){
        this.initData();
},
initData(){
        let bpIds = this.get('bpIds'),
            data = [],
            length = bpIds.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            let uri = "this is a uri";
            let key = bpIds[i];
            /* jshint loopfunc:true */
            $.getJSON(uri).then((result) => {
                let o = {
                    key:parseInt(key),
                    value:result.result.name
                };
                data.push(o);
            });
        }
        this.set('data',data);
    }
});
```

This component is used to get data and render itself with the bp_ids.

However, I found it work when I change the js like that:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
didReceiveAttrs(){
        this.initData();
},
initData(){
        let data = [];
        data=[
        {key:1,value:'value1'},
        {key:2,value:'value2'}]
        this.set('data',data);
    }
});
```

I really don't know why. How to make the component works when I want to get data from back-end in the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `didReceiveAttrs` hook will be called for initial render and re-render too.
- One-time initialization can be done in `init` method
- Array initialization should be done in `init` method ( that's safe one)
- For array update, use `pushObject` instead of `push`
- After doing some nitpicking, your component code would look like something below,

`export default Ember.Component.extend({
    data: null,
    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        this.set('data', []);
        let bpIds = this.get('bpIds'),
            length = bpIds.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            let uri = "this is a uri";
            let key = bpIds[i];
            /* jshint loopfunc:true */
            $.getJSON(uri).then((result) => {
                let o = {
                    key: parseInt(key),
                    value: result.result.name
                };
                this.get('data').pushObject(o);
            });
        }
    }
});`

Comment: Yes, after using `pushObject` instead of `push`, it works. But how about delete an element form an array?  I'm now using `array.splice(i,1)` to delete the element, but it dosen't work.

Comment: As the third advice you give, what if I want initialize the array every time when the bp_ids route give to the component, would it be safe to use `didReceiveAttrs`?

Comment: I found `array.removeObject(ele)` works to remove an element from an array.

Comment: But I still don't know when to use `this.set()` or `pushObject`? And why I directly set an array to 'data' and it works, but when I push data to array one by one and then use `this.set` it doesn't work?

Comment: You might need to refer [Objects in Ember](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/object-model/). for arrays there is ember equivalent method to use, you can refer [Enumerables](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/object-model/enumerables/) part in ember guides